# Help Identifying SMD IC component

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

It is a 6-pin SOT with the marking MaDQb or MaDOb. The left IC. It is on a PCB in a rechargable flashlight. [image: MaDQb]

Comment: This seems like a tough nut to crack. Could you perhaps trace out the circuitry or provide sharper photos of board (both sides)? Could at least help narrow it down to battery, LED driver or other.

Comment: The soldering job is beyond poor. There are likely multiple problems here - expect this thing to break at any moment even if you replace the IC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Shiningic(裕芯电子) Li-Ion battery charger. Either the [YX4096](https://www.shiningic.com/zh/productdetail.aspx?detailid=181&classid1=0101&classid2=010106) or the [YX4057C](https://taoic.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/7581/product/tssemi168_1601348162000.pdf). It's a bit confusing, the seemingly offical site of this manufacturer lists the picture below for a YX4096 that is availabe in a SOT23-6 package, but there is no datasheet to be found. There is a datasheet for the YX4057C and when searching for images you find the same markings as in the picture for the YX4096.

[image]

Old answer:

Probably a Li-Ion battery charger, similar to the [TP4057](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_TPOWER-TP4057ST26P_C440390.pdf), based on the connections. I couldn't find one with the same markings, but there are a lot of these around and not all named TP4057, like the [AP5054C](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1808311811_Wuxi-Chipown-Micro-electronics-AP5054CES6_C130349.pdf), [SD8067](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_SHOUDING-SD8067B_C250802.pdf) or [SE9012](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2202131930_Seaward-Elec-SE9012-HF_C2838448.pdf), just to name a few. They all have the same pinout though, as shown in second image.

[image]

[image]